# Line spacing in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, phpstorm

I want to set **line spacing** in *PhpStorm* and I have found it in *Settings*.

But it does not work as I want to. It just adds some more space above the text and I want to have **the text in the middle of the line**. Is there any way how to make this possible?

This space above the text is so ugly and useless. *I attach a picture where you can see the problem.*

[image: What is my problem.]

Comment: I think you are looking for **letter-spacing**. I really don't know if it can be achieved without changing the font.

Comment: I have the same issue with android studio. Essentially when I change the font size, the line height does not (visibly) change. This is regardless of the line spacing value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by the developers, the text are now middled as you put more line spacing.
So the text are now middled (newest version).

Proff:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try Meslo LG font.
Meslo LG is a customized version of Apple’s Menlo-Regular font. The LG stands for Line Gap. I use Meslo LG L to create a bit of spacing between lines and keep the text in the middle. Best thing about it, you can use it in other apps like Terminal.

https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font